# Showing that an unknown IVP solution is an even function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given the following IVP:
$$y'=f(x,y)=4x^3 e^{-|x^2+y|}$$
$$y(x_0)=y_0$$

I need to show that the IVP has a single solution in $(-\infty,\infty)$, and that it is an even function.

I was able to show, after some struggles that $f(x,y)$ fulfills Lipschiz condition with respect to $y$ in every closed vertical infinite rectangle of the form $[a,b]\times(-\infty,\infty)$ (using showing it separately for the functions in the composition of $4x^3e^z$ with $|x^2+y|$), thus there is a single unique solution in $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Yet, I fail to show that the solution $u(x)$ is an even function.

The problem arises when I tried to show that the derivative of the solution, $u'(x)$, is odd, since $f(x,u)$ depends on $u(x)$ itself, which leads me to a cyclic argument.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You can solve it explicitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $\tilde y(t)=y(-t)$. Then we see by inserting, that $\tilde y$ solves the same IVP as $y$. Since you have proven uniqueness, it follows that $\tilde y=y$. This proves that $y$ is even.

Comment: One can assume that $x_0=0$, then $\tilde y(x_0)=y(-0)=y(x_0)=y_0$. 
The reason why we can assume $x_0=0$ is because of the uniqueness of the IVP for all initial values, meaning we can look at the solution $y$ of the original solution, evaluate it at $0$ and use this for the IVP problem with $x_0=0$ and $y(0)=y_0$. Then apply the above arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure how showing that $y(-t)$ is a solution to the IVP any different than directly showing that $y'(t)$ is odd. I would need to differentiate $y(-t)$, which will give me: $(-1) \cdot (-4t^3 e^{-|{t^2 + y(-t)}|})$ and I get to the same problem of showing that $y(-t)=y(t)$.

Comment: We have $\tilde y(t)'=-y(-t)' =- 4 (-t)^3 e^{|t^2+y(-t)|} = 4t^3 e^{-|t^2 +\tilde y(t)|}$, meaning $\tilde y$ solves the ode. The initial value is also the same, as stated in my previous comment.

Comment: You're right, I Missed the fact that the function $y(-t)$ itself is what I expect to be in the exponent in order to fulfill the condition for the IVP, Thanks.